Alternating Least Squares training vs inference
I use als.AlternatingLeastSquares from implicit Python package. While training on sparse CSR matrix is efficient and takes ~10-15 minutes (with default number of latent parameters and iterations), the inference takes a little more than hour. Is it normal? How to optimize inference? Usually ML algorithms are quite the opposite : the training takes much longer than inference. Both training and inference is on few million users.
I tried to reduce the number of latent parameters but the model quality obviously gets worse.
